# ember 2.18 how to set a record back to isDeleted = false

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

i have a list of files,
and a history of these files.
when i delete a file in the current latest version, the ember store sets this file to isDeleted = true.
so when i get the list of files for an older revision with this deleted file, it is hidden, because the ember store thinks it is deleted.
so i tested to set the record with
myFile.set('isDeleted',false); but it doesnt work, "the property is read only".

note: i don't want a full rollback of attributes, i just want to make them set the flag isDeleted to false.

Answer (score 0):

So it sounds like you don't want to use `rollbackAttributes()`.  I think that as long as the record remains in the store, you can't deal with this properly.  So as far as I know, your only option is:

After you delete, call [`unloadRecord()`](https://emberjs.com/api/ember-data/3.4/classes/DS.Store/methods/unloadRecord?anchor=unloadRecord)

edit:  [this seems related](https://discuss.emberjs.com/t/reusing-ids-for-soft-deleted-records/13715/6), but may not be relevant for your use case.